# How to rotate elements regarding to another element?

Tags: javascript, rotation, trigonometry

My fiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gopifiddle/p21bg5pb/)

```
<body>
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper" style="">
                <div id="container">
          <div class="handles">
            <span data-clickable="true" id="rotate-handle"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
                <div id="item_1" class="item" style=""></div>
                <div id="item_2" class="item" style=""></div>
                <div id="item_3" class="item" style=""></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
function rotateStart(e) {
            startAngle = Math.atan2(e.clientX - contatiner_x + contatiner_width / 2, - (e.clientY - container_y + container_height / 2) )*(180/Math.PI);
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', rotate, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', rotateStop, false);
        }

        function rotate(e) {
            var angle         = Math.atan2(e.clientX - contatiner_x + contatiner_width / 2, - (e.clientY - container_y + container_height / 2) )*(180/Math.PI);
            var rotate_angle = angle - startAngle;
            contatier.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 100px) rotateZ('+rotate_angle+'deg)';
        }

        function rotateStop() {
            window.removeEventListener('mousemove', rotate, false);
        }
```

I am working on it for just experiment.
I just want rotate all items along with container without transform origin.

PS : Rotate container by top right handle, 
     Container and items are siblings.

Comment: You need to put the items inside the container https://jsfiddle.net/p21bg5pb/1/

Comment: "_without transform origin_" Not possible, rotation is always done around the transform origin. You can calculate an "offset" related to the origin, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the items outside, then just apply the same transformation to them as you are applying to the container

```
document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 100px) rotateZ(' + rotate_angle + 'deg)';
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var rotate_handle = document.getElementById('rotate-handle'),
  contatier = document.getElementById("container");
rotate_handle.addEventListener('mousedown', rotateStart, false);

let contatiner_x = 50,
  container_y = 100,
  contatiner_width = 240,
  container_height = 300;

function rotateStart(e) {
  startAngle = Math.atan2(e.clientX - contatiner_x + contatiner_width / 2, -(e.clientY - container_y + container_height / 2)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', rotate, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', rotateStop, false);
}

function rotate(e) {
  var angle = Math.atan2(e.clientX - contatiner_x + contatiner_width / 2, -(e.clientY - container_y + container_height / 2)) * (180 / Math.PI);
  var rotate_angle = angle - startAngle;
  contatier.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 100px) rotateZ(' + rotate_angle + 'deg)';
  document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.transform = 'translate(50px, 100px) rotateZ(' + rotate_angle + 'deg)';
  });
}

function rotateStop() {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', rotate, false);
}
```

```css
#container {
  transform: translate(50px, 100px);
  width: 240px;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  outline: 3px solid #000;
}

#rotate-handle {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25%;
  padding: 1px;
  background: red;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
}

#item_1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px; top:100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

#item_2 {
  width: 190px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px; top:300px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000
}

#item_3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 75px; top:200px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="wrapper" style="">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="handles">
        <span data-clickable="true" id="rotate-handle"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="item_1" class="item" style=""></div>
    <div id="item_2" class="item" style=""></div>
    <div id="item_3" class="item" style=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could not add container dynamically, so that i want to keep items along with container those are selected within container. I need it by each items; angle and (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: Thanks but, items should be with in container as initial.